# Proof of even like powers?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, exponentiation

Can someone show me the proof that difference of like even powers of any two numbers is divisible by the sum of the bases?

Answer (score 6):

HINT: $(a^{2n} - b^{2n}) = (a^n - b^n)(a^n + b^n) =...$

---

Added:

In response to a comment, this proof does *not* use logarithms.

The expression $a^n + b^n$ is called "the sum of nth powers". Notice that "the sum of the bases" is just $(a + b)$, which is the first factor in [the factorization of the sum of nth powers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Sum.2Fdifference_of_two_nth_powers).

Comment: He probably needs a second hint, namely that different things happen when $n$ odd and $n$ even...

Comment: User, see hint #2, above! (@N. S. indeed, I was hoping to evoke some interaction with our first-time OP)

Comment: I can delete my hint if you prefer :)

Comment: @N. S. interacting with *anyone* is fine with me! ;)

Comment: I don't know why people voted my hint more, your hint is actually cleaner and more elementary :)

Comment: I strongly believe in the "rich get richer" phenomenon on MsE... so after I gave yours the first vote, it was all uphill! It's not a big deal to me. I get random down votes on old questions and answers, and I've authored a top 5 (6?) answer (from an old account). I just hope people learn math and enjoy the process.

Comment: Still not getting it guys =/. Two questions. Does the proof involve logarithms? Isn't the above expression in the most simplified form? I was thinking... I need to show that (a^n - b^n)(a^n+b^n) = (a+b)i, then I took the log of both sides and got nowhere

Comment: Well if you ever return to MSE, I hope you find this solution more fulfilling!

Answer (score 6):

Alternate Hint: $a \equiv-b \pmod{a+b}$

Comment: You want `\equiv` instead of `\cong`...

Comment: I need to study the mod operator a bit more, will get back to this, thanks for reply